# Porting multithreaded window ce app to win32

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, mfc, windows-ce

I am trying to do the opposite of the usual. We have a legacy WinCE app which now needs to be ported to the Win32 platform, so that it can work as a simulator of the actual app.

I have managed to get the code compiled and most of the things have started working. But the problem is, the app is heavily multi-threaded. All the threads worked in sync when the app was on WinCE, but, on windows there is absolutely no sync between them.

The app was communicating on serial ports but for long times invalidate doesn't work. At other times, the receiving thread hangs up. Sometimes the data isn't sent at all. Sometimes the thread sends data multiple times over and over again.

Any idea what the difference is between multi-threading in WinCE and Win32? What could be causing this sort of problem?

The app is so big that a design change is next to impossible. Any advice on what I should look into?

Comment: It could be that Win32 exposes threading bugs in the program that you didn't detect on CE, since there are so many more context switches and background processes running on an average drowsy PC. It could also be some API function that is implemented differently. But without any actual code shown, I don't think anyone can answer this.

Comment: I agree with Lundin.  The PC has simply uncovered syncrhonization bugs in the original code.  Make sure you're synchronizing resource access with Critical Sections, etc. and the problem will likely go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, all the threads were not getting enough time to process data, which caused tons of timeouts. All i had to do was, put some locks where data was being corrupted and Change `Sleep(0)` to `Sleep(5)`. 
This reduced CPU usage form 95% to barely 10% and got rid of all the problems.